# How to remove the last new line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to split the text by new lines then stored into array that the array return the length was `5`. But my input file has four lines. How to remove the last new line.

```
$.get('patrn', function (file) {
var filedata = file;
var seq = new Array;
seq = filedata.split("\n");
var seqpass = new seqleng(seq);
}, 'text');

function seqleng (b){
//Pdat = b.replace(/[\n]/gm,""); //But this is not working
var Pdat = b;
alert(Pdat.length);
}
```

My input file Like this

```
PQEMTGKPLFIVE
AAAG
MTG
KPLFIVE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already splits the string into an array. You cannot use regexp to work on arrays (regexps are for strings), you need in this case explicit code:

```
function seqleng(b) {
    if (b[b.length-1] === "") {
        b.pop();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the string before splitting with [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) (IE9+). It will remove whitespaces including new lines from the beginning and the end of the string:

```
var filedata = file.trim();
seq = filedata.split("\n");
```

If IE8 support is needed, then jQuery comes with similar utility [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/):

```
var filedata = $.trim(file);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Any possible way for `trim` function to support previous version of IE8.

Comment: You can extend String prototype like in the MDN article I referenced. Or you can use jQuery analog.